# Upload Image Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am not able to upload an image using pythons Selenium:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uploadButton"]').send_keys("image_path")
```

[image]

[image]

An this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload file with Selenium like you trying to do you should use `//input[@type="file"]` element.
So please try this, it should work:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys("image_path")
```

Comment: Not working ://

Comment: Maybe you just missing a wait? If not - can you share a link to that web page?

Comment: Yes, but it is FSK18: https://www.molligundwillig.de/lp/lp8#b   At one point while registration you can upload a image...^^

Comment: On https://www.molligundwillig.de/completeprofile/pictureupload I see the UI button to upload the image as well as `//input[@type="file"]` element to be used with selenium. So it should work. Maybe your "image_path" is wrong? What happens when you try uploading the file with command I mentioned?

Comment: Used relative path, with absolute it's working. THX!!

Comment: You are welcome! You could use relative path as well, you just need to know how to use it :) If you wish, you can ask about that in a new, separate question